# Kibana Average Not as expected

Tags: kibana

I am a newbie trying to learn kibana.  I have inserted this data..Just passed,failed and skipped count for test cases into elastic.

testMethodsSummary.passed:0 testMethodsSummary.failed:1 testMethodsSummary.skipped:0 _id:AWBP0yDXO9VGNRQOwYSD _type:uc _index:msm _score:1
    testMethodsSummary.passed:1 testMethodsSummary.failed:0 testMethodsSummary.skipped:0 _id:AWBP0wHiO9VGNRQOwYSC _type:uc _index:msm _score:1
    testMethodsSummary.passed:5 testMethodsSummary.failed:1 testMethodsSummary.skipped:0 _id:AWBP0tthO9VGNRQOwYSB _type:bat _index:msm _score:1
    testMethodsSummary.passed:1 testMethodsSummary.failed:0 testMethodsSummary.skipped:6 _id:AWBP0qTxO9VGNRQOwYSA _type:bat _index:msm _score:1

When I query the count come out ok.

"aggregations": {
    "total_fail": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "total_skipped": {
      "value": 6
    },
    "total_pass": {
      "value": 7
    }
  }

but when trying to get average .. the average pass is not 7/15 - I don't even know where those numbers are coming from.
"aggregations": {
    "avg_fail": {
      "value": 0.5
    },
    "avg_skip": {
      "value": 1.5
    },
    "avg_pass": {
      "value": 1.75
    }
  }

Can anyone please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Average aggregation in Elasticsearch are calculated over all the documents.

For more info on average aggregation :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html

> aggregations": { "avg_fail": { "value": 0.5 }, "avg_skip": { "value":
>   1.5 }, "avg_pass": { "value": 1.75 } }

For avg_fail its (sum of all the fail)/(total doc count in the index) i.e. 2/4 = 0.5

Similarly for avg_skip its 6/4 = 1.5 and for avg_pass its 7/4 = 1.75

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   Is there anyway that I can the actual average like the total pass/total # of test cases rather than the document total.